# Change background for all elements in a header, and leave the rest of the page

Tags: html, reactjs, sass, gatsby

I'm making a gatsby site and it has a `layout` and `header` component that I use to build pages. I also have individual stylesheets for each component (`layout.module.scss` and `header.module.scss`).

Here's my code:

```js
/* layout.js */
import React from "react"

import * as layoutStyles from "./layout.module.scss"

import Header from "./header"

const Layout = props => {
  return (
    <div className={layoutStyles.container}>
      <div className={layoutStyles.content}>
        <Header />
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

```js
/* header.js */
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import * as headerStyles from "./header.module.scss"

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className={headerStyles.header}>
      <Link to="/" className={headerStyles.logo}>
        Test Site
      </Link>
      <nav className={headerStyles.nav}>
        <ul class={headerStyles.navList}>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about" class={headerStyles.navItem}>About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/projects" class={headerStyles.navItem}>Projects</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/contact" class={headerStyles.navItem}>Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

```css
/* layout.module.scss */
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```css
/* header.module.scss */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@400;500&display=swap');

* {
  background: #F2EEE4;
}

.header {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem 5rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0.25rem 1rem #aaa;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.logo {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #5065A8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;

}

.nav-item {
  color: #5065A8;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Doing that causes the whole page to take the colour from `header.module.scss` so is there a way to change just the background for the header without specifying the background for every single element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cancel the global background

```
* {
  background: #F2EEE4;
}
```

and the added background just for the `header`

Comment: I should've clarified, I already tried that. But then the logo and nav in the header still have a white background

Comment: Because you have another global background in layout.module.scss, what happens when you cancel also that one?

Comment: that fixes it, but how can I style the rest of the page a different colour excluding that without that line (assuming I need to change it to a colour that isn't white)?

Comment: You should give your background color to your main wrapper in your component. In this case it would be for <div className={layoutStyles.container}> in layout.module.scss . Using * effects all components because that is global

Comment: that fixes it, I had to apply it to the .content class instead of .container but that fixed it, thanks